# If I wanted to make a database with "reactions" similar to facebook, would this architecture make sense?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm trying to understand if the following design makes sense for something like facebook reactions. My thinking is that each reaction would ultimately be a list of user_ids. 
Example: 
reaction_like =[19,24,36,75]
with [19,24,36,75] being people's userids

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  phone_number varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE posts (
  user_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  post_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  post_text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  reaction_happy BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
  reaction_sad BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
  reaction_surprised BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
  reaction_like BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need a third table. Remove `reaction_happy`, `reaction_sad`, etc. from the `posts` table. And then make something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reactions (
  reaction_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  post_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  type ENUM('happy','sad','surprised','like') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (reaction_id)
)
```

Also, for performance, you'd probably want to add indexes on all of the ID columns. You'd want to `LEFT JOIN` `users` and `reactions` to the `posts` table when you're trying to do something like render the main feed in the way Facebook presents it.

Comment: Thanks, man yea that makes sense. How do you feel about using BIGINT vs something else, just curious? I voted you up btw but since im new they don't show it yet.

Comment: I generally just use INT(10), if I'm using an auto incremented integer for the primary key. INT(10) will do ~4 billion rows, which is more than enough for most projects. BIGINT will take up slightly more disk space and be marginally slower. If this turns out to be a serious project with thousands of users, it only takes a few seconds to alter the field later. You'll most likely have a lot of bigger performance problems at that scale, though.

Only other case for BIGINT would be if the table has frequent inserts/deletions and runs out of IDs quickly, even if the total number of records is low

Comment: Also, if it's not a big deal, and if you're satisfied with my answer, please "Accept" in addition to upvoting it :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i would just use `type VARCHAR(<value>) NOT NULL,` instead off `type ENUM('happy','sad','surprised','like') NOT NULL,`  .. ENUM's can be wierd to work with

Comment: In general, reducing the number of possible inputs into your program is the safer route. An ENUM will prevent you from reading or writing an invalid value. Every ORM I've used handles MySQL ENUMs just fine. What makes them weird?

Comment: thanks, guys appreciate all the feedback here.